# How to insert a String into a String array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, java.util.scanner

I have the following code that gets a user input:

```
456589 maths 7.8 english 8.6 end
654564 literature 7.5 physics 5.5 chemistry 9.5 end
```

and stores the code at the beginning of the sentence in an array called grades and the code in another array called person. I need to use these two arrays in order to display later each person's average grade in each lesson.

My code is the following

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Student
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            String currentAnswer = "";
            String userWords = "";
            String am = "";
            String subj = "";
            float grad;
            float[] grades = new float[100];
            String[] person = new String[100];

            System.out.println("Enter your a.m. as well as the subjects which you sat in finals");

                while(!currentAnswer.equals("end"))
                {
                    currentAnswer = s.nextLine(); // reads the number or word
                    userWords += currentAnswer + " ";
                    if(currentAnswer.equals("000000"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("The sequence of numbers you entered is: "+userWords);
                        System.out.println("Exiting...");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }

                    String[] wordsplit = currentAnswer.split(" ");
                    for (String str : wordsplit)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            grade = Float.parseFloat(str);
                        }
                        catch(NumberFormatException ex)
                        {
                            person = str;
                        }

                    }

                }                   
                    System.out.println("Enter your a.m. as well as the subjects which you sat in finals");  
        }
    }
```

The error message concers the lines

```
grades = Float.parseFloat(str);
person = str` --> `String cannot be converted to String[]`<br>
```

Seems that converting a String into a String array is prohibited. What can I do in order to avoid this?

thank you!!

Comment: Can you please explain more about the error

Comment: Yes of course. Whenever I run it I do not get the desired result in the arrays grade and person. Also when I try to display the following output --> ( 456589 has an average result of <average_result>) I also get an error message

Comment: `person` is an array, `str` is a String - totally different types. You can't assign one to another. You should do some research on how to set elements of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Look again on the code
`grade = Float.parseFloat(str);` and vars declaration
`float grad; float[] grades = new float[100]`

Cannot see any `grade` !

This cannot compile for sure !

Comment: Thank you I fixed that but i still get the same error that I can't convert a float to a float[] and a string to a string[]. Any ideas on how I can fic that? thank you!

Comment: Yes. In your case you have a predefined `split return`:  `[int, string, float, string, float, string] `. Just assign directly one by one. Eg: `grad = Float.parseFloat(wordsplit[2])`. No need loop (can be used, but keep as simple as you can)

Answer (score 0):

You defined `grad` and used `grade`

Initially when you defined you used the variable name `grad`

```
float grad;
```

But you used `grade` here

```
grade = Float.parseFloat(str);
```

Also try to use `ArrayList` instead of `String` array

Comment: Thank you, but I used grades on purpose because I want the grades of each students to be in the grades array

Comment: for ```grade``` you defined ```grad```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message speaks for itself, you are trying to assign `String` into `String[]`, since it is an array, you want to call something like `person[0] = str`, same thing with grade, you want to call `grade[0] = Float.parseFloat(str)`
... but ofc you probably want to store number of persons inserted into the array, so you create an `int inserted = 0` and then call `grade[inserted] = Float.parseFloat(str)` and also call `inserted++` after that (or simply call `grade[inserted++] = Float.parseFloat(str)`.. I assume you will need one integer for persons and one for grades

Answer (score 0):

Try using ArrayLists, there are more forgiving than arrays, and simple to learn. You can see more about them here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp

If you want to use ArrayList, you must include this in begging of your file.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```